# Android onKey... events are not being invoked in Activity

Tags: android, react-native, audio, android-activity

I'm working on a project that includes voice calls, and there is some issue that I can't change audio level when in call.

Project is running on React Native 0.64.2

I tried listening to the hardware buttons to change the audio myself with AudioManager. But the issue here is when a user tries to hold down a volume button onKeyDown is never invoked, it is only invoked when out of call. Does anyone have any idea what seems to be the problem.

Because it's difficult for other people to test, what happens when I execute my code & press the volume buttons, for short & long periods:

[onKey... listeners with logs in ReactActivity/AppCompatActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRSes.png)

[Result of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tigzB.png)

To takeover the audio I created my own package so I can set the audio channel needed at that time. (I linked it to the MainActivity, of the project so hardware presses will normally be executed (according to me))

I tested without any bluetooth device connect, used the phone audio directly.

Java Logs when trying to change audio without any added listeners in MainActivity:

```
12-27 09:02:54.186  8418  8418 I TelecomFramework: VoiceConnectionService: silence TC@1600_1: (SSTSI.sR->TSI.sR)->CS.s->H.CS.s(a/cast)@E-iVY
12-27 09:02:54.186  8418  8418 D RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onSilence called
12-27 09:02:54.187  8418  8418 V RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] sendEventToJS, eventName: RNCallKeepOnSilenceIncomingCall, bound: true, hasListeners: true args : { NativeMap: {"name":"New phonecall from +PHONENUMBER,”callUUID":"cf5027c1-927d-476f-ac3d-adb944ad52d4","handle":"%2B32476077374"} }
12-27 09:02:54.189  5288  5288 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1926 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:834 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:834 com.sec.android.diagmonagent.sa.receiver.CFLogReceiver.a:4 com.sec.android.diagmonagent.sa.receiver.CFLogReceiver.onReceive:4
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  2803 D InputReader: Input event(7): value=0 when=976610.330729
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  2803 D WindowManager: interceptKeyTq keycode=25 interactive=true keyguardActive=false policyFlags=22000000
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  1867 D PhoneWindowManagerExt: Can not take screenshot, triggered=false event=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=976610330729000, downTime=976610247769000, deviceId=3, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  1867 D PhoneWindowManagerExt: Can not take screenshot, triggered=false event=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=976610330729000, downTime=976610247769000, deviceId=3, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  1867 D PhoneWindowManagerExt: Can not take screenshot, triggered=false event=null
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  2803 D PhoneWindowManagerExt: interceptKeyTq code=25 down=false repeatCount=0 displayId=-1 interactive=true
12-27 09:02:54.263  1732  2803 D WindowManager: interceptKeyTq interceptKeyResult=1
12-27 09:02:54.264  1732  2802 D PowerManagerService: [api] userActivityFromNative :  (event: 1 flags: 32768 displayId: 0) eventTime = 976610330
12-27 09:02:54.265  1732  2802 D WindowManager: interceptKeyTi keyCode=25 down=false repeatCount=0 keyguardOn=true canceled=false
12-27 09:02:54.266  1732  2802 D PhoneWindowManagerExt: interceptKeyTi code=25 down=false repeatCount=0 displayId=-1 interactive=true
12-27 09:02:54.266  1732  2802 I InputDispatcher: Delivering key to (8418): VD action: 0x1 (0), f=0x8, m=0x0, d=0, '4cf5923'
12-27 09:02:54.266  5436  5436 I SemDvfsHyPerManager: acquire hyper - TABoost/5436@17, type = 1090523139
12-27 09:02:54.267  1429  1465 I HYPER-HAL: [RequestManager.cpp]releaseLocked(): Released ID : 14870348
12-27 09:02:54.267  1429  1465 I HYPER-HAL: [RequestManager.cpp]acquire(): Acquired ID : 14870348  [5436 / 17]    HINT :      list : [TABoost / 1] [TIMEOUT / 1500]
12-27 09:02:54.268 27723 27723 I HBD     : HoneyBoardService onKeyUp r:1524eac7 consumed:false 1
12-27 09:02:54.269  8418  8418 I ViewRootImpl@6aa7f50[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
12-27 09:02:54.270  1732  6421 D MediaSessionService: dispatchVolumeKeyEvent, pkg=—, opPkg=—, pid=8418, uid=10573, asSystem=true, event=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=976610330729000, downTime=976610247769000, deviceId=3, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }, stream=-2147483648, musicOnly=false
12-27 09:02:54.270  1732  6421 D MediaSessionService: Adjusting com.android.server.telecom/HeadsetMediaButton (userId=0) by 0. flags=4116, suggestedStream=-2147483648, preferSuggestedStream=false
12-27 09:02:54.271  1732  2985 D AS.AudioService: adjustSuggestedStreamVolume() stream=0, flags=4112, caller=android, volControlStream=-1, userSelect=false
12-27 09:02:54.271  1732  2985 I Telecom:SamsungTelecomServiceImpl: isInCall - callingPackage : android
12-27 09:02:54.271  1732  2985 D AS.AudioService: adjustStreamVolume() stream=0, dir=0, flags=4112, caller=android
12-27 09:02:54.272  1732  2985 I Telecom:SamsungTelecomServiceImpl: isInCall - callingPackage : android
12-27 09:02:54.272  1732  2985 V AS.AudioDeviceBroker: requestedCommunicationDevice, device: null mode owner pid: 1732
12-27 09:02:54.273  3164  3736 D vol.VolumeDialogControl: onVolumeChangedW stream = 0, flags = 4112, lastAudibleStreamVolume = 6, changed = false, showUI = false, dualAudio = false
```

Conclusion of java logs:

WORKS (OUTBOUND)

```
12-21 13:14:39.651  1732  6426 D MediaSessionService: Adjusting suggestedStream=-2147483648 by 0. flags=4116, preferSuggestedStream=false, session=null
12-21 13:14:40.184  1732  6429 D MediaSessionService: dispatchVolumeKeyEvent, pkg=---, opPkg=---, pid=24696, uid=10559, asSystem=true, event=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=891222737322000, downTime=891222737322000, deviceId=3, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }, stream=-2147483648, musicOnly=false
```

NOT WORKING (INBOUND)

```
12-21 13:15:47.383  1732  3869 D MediaSessionService: Adjusting com.android.server.telecom/HeadsetMediaButton (userId=0) by 0. flags=4116, suggestedStream=-2147483648, preferSuggestedStream=false
12-21 13:15:47.585  1732  5561 D MediaSessionService: dispatchVolumeKeyEvent, pkg=---, opPkg=---, pid=24696, uid=10559, asSystem=true, event=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=891290283020000, downTime=891290190142000, deviceId=3, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }, stream=-2147483648, musicOnly=false
```

Module:

```
package com.---.audioTakeover;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Integer;
import android.util.Log;

public class RNAudioTakeoverModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private static Integer channel = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

  public RNAudioTakeoverModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RNAudioTakeover";
  }

  public static Integer get() {
    return channel;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public static void set(Integer value) {
    Integer[] existingStreams = {
      AudioManager.STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY,
      AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
      AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,
      AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
      AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
      AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
      AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
      AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
      AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE
    };

    try {
      if (value == (Integer)value && Arrays.asList(existingStreams).contains(value)) {
        channel = value;
      } else {
        channel = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        channel = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
    }
  }
}
```

Package:

```
package com.---.audioTakeover;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RNAudioTakeoverPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new RNAudioTakeoverModule(reactContext));
    }

    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.---.mc.purecloud;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import java.lang.Integer;

//DSL
import android.view.WindowManager;
import io.wazo.callkeep.RNCallKeepModule; 
import com.overlaypermission.OverlayPermissionPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.---.hideScreenshot.HideScreenshotModule;
import com.---.audioTakeover.RNAudioTakeoverModule;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  private static final String DEFAULT_CHANNEL = "DEFAULT";
  private static final String SILENT_CHANNEL = "SILENT";
  private static final String TEL = "tel";
  public Bundle mInitialProps = null;
  private AudioManager audio;

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Testing";
  }

  @Override
  public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
      return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
          @Override
          protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
              return mInitialProps;
          }
      };
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      switch (requestCode) {
          case RNCallKeepModule.REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
              RNCallKeepModule.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
              break;
      }
  }

  private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, WritableMap params) {
    try{
      reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit(eventName, params);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      Log.d("TEST","ERROR "+ e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      if (HideScreenshotModule.get()) {
          getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (HideScreenshotModule.get()) {
          getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (HideScreenshotModule.get()) {
      if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
      } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
      }
    }
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
      String action = intent.getAction();
      Uri data = intent.getData();
      String stringUri="";
      if (data!=null){
      stringUri = data.toString();
        if (stringUri.contains(TEL)) {
            WritableMap idData = Arguments.createMap();
            
            idData.putString("tel", stringUri);
            sendEvent(getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext(), "INCOMINGTELFROMOUTSIDEMC", idData);
        }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getReactInstanceManager().onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }

  // needed for react-native-screens
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);

    //DSL
    mInitialProps = new Bundle();
    Uri test = getIntent().getData();
    String stringUri="";
    if (test!=null)
    stringUri = test.toString();
    if (stringUri.contains(TEL)) {
      mInitialProps.putString(TEL, stringUri);
    }
    audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    //END DSL

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        createDefaultNotificationChannel(mNotificationManager);
      //  createSilentNotificationChannel(mNotificationManager);
    }

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY SHORTCUT " + keyCode);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY UP " + keyCode);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY DOWN " + keyCode);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY MULTIPLE " + keyCode + " " + ((Integer)repeatCount).toString());
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY LONG " + keyCode);
    return true;
  }

  // This works, but executes like keyUp (only once every press)
  /*@Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
  
    Log.e("@YANNICK", "KEY EVENT " + keyCode);

    switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(RNAudioTakeoverModule.get(), AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(RNAudioTakeoverModule.get(), AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
      default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
      }
  }*/
  
  private void createDefaultNotificationChannel(NotificationManager mNotificationManager) {
    NotificationChannel defaultChannel = new NotificationChannel(
        DEFAULT_CHANNEL, 
        "Default channel",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    );

    defaultChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
    defaultChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(defaultChannel);
  }

  private void createSilentNotificationChannel(NotificationManager mNotificationManager) {
      NotificationChannel silentChannel = new NotificationChannel(
          SILENT_CHANNEL,
          "Silent channel",
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
      );
      silentChannel.setSound(null, null);
      silentChannel.enableLights(false);
      silentChannel.setVibrationPattern(null);
      silentChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
      mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(silentChannel);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From short doc.

> Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity.

Probably the press is processed by another activity element

Comment: Added java logs to the question, I think it has something to do with the MediaSessionService. But don't know how or where I could start changing this.